# JavaFX - FXMLLoader can't load my fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I know so many question have about this, but didn't found the answer what gonna help me out.

So here is my hierarchy:

[Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX9QY.png)

I tried so many thing like:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/main/fxml/CharacterSelect.fxml"));

Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main/fxml/CharacterSelect.fxml"));

Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("src/main/fxml/CharacterSelect.fxml"));

Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/src/main/fxml/CharacterSelect.fxml"));

Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("src/main/fxml/CharacterSelect.fxml"));

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("fxml/CharacterSelect.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load(); 

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxml/CharacterSelect.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();

...
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("main/fxml/CharacterSelect.fxml"));
```

Since this structure/hierarchy must be applied, I have to get it to work.

Controller Class value for the `CharacterSelect.fxml` is:

```
main.fxml.CharacterSelectController
```

**Remark:** 
The program working if the fxml is not in the main folder just next to it with :

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/CharacterSelect.fxml"));
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Comment: Controller is in main.Charact... and not main.fxml.Ch... be careful
Is FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/CharacterSelect.fxml")); working ? (no '/' before fxml)

Comment: Thank you! It's working again :)